# Reinstall .NET Framework on Windows 8?

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows-8, .net-4.5

After uninstall a Visual Studio plugin(ANTS profiler) I get exceptions like :

> UnauthorizedAccessException occured Access to the path
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\~AspAccessCheck_7d9f07e52084.tmp' is denied.

In Windows 7 i would try to run the asp_regiis to fix this but this is not possible in Windows. I have tried to set the ASP.NET folder to NOT read only but that does not fix the problem.

I have tried unactivate/activate the feutures in controlpanel but that does not really remove and reinstall .NET framework becouse it is infact a core part.

If its not possible to uninstall/install, is there any way to repair .NET or will I have to reinstall the entire OS for this?

*Not that impressed with the ANTS software*

Edit 1 :

It is not possible to change the Permission on the framework folder. Also its a 64 bits verson of Windows 8, should it not use Framework64 instead of Framework?

Edit 2 : Windows have not saved any recover point more then the one today. The Ants virus was installed yesterday, so no luck there eather.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstallation was the only working soultion.

Answer (score 1):

To repair inbox components like .net 4.5 or other Windows files, run this [DISM command](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx) from a [cmd prompt which is started as admin](https://superuser.com/questions/497252/how-to-access-the-administrator-command-prompt-in-windows-8):

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

Comment: It took its time but it did run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to download and reinstall .netFramework?

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Comment: This is what the installation says : Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 is already a part of this operating system.  You do not need to install the .NET Framework 4.5 redistributable.

Comment: What are you trying to install or uninstall that caused this problem?

Comment: I used the link you provided.

Comment: What are you trying to install or uninstall that caused this problem, before my suggestion?

Comment: I installed Ants Profiler trial version and Visual Studio could still debug my websites. But when I uninstalled Ants Profiler after 5 min of use not any of my websites could be debugged with VS2012 any more. I first get the stated exception then alot for followup exceptions.

Comment: You tried to change the Target Framework in the project properties?

Comment: I have now tried to create a new Webform webapplication and that do run as it should it seems? I have also tried an older project of mine that I know worked but not anymore. I dont get this at all. I have not made any changes the the websites

Comment: Changing the .net from 4.5 to 4.0 do nothing more then generates more problems. But even when I remove the errors I get the same exceptions when debugging as before.

Comment: A strange thing is that even if the exceptions is thrown the website is displayed in the browser? I dont get this, Im not to happy with ANTS ;)

Comment: Okay, I found somthing, if I uncheck all checkboxes under Debug > Exceptions the site will run fine?